# Logical Shift Left not culling when fed longs in java?

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

I have a hexadecimal long that I'm performing a LSL on, and it seems to just be expanding the string, instead of shifting it.

long R, before the operation is:

10000000000000000000000001101011

```
R<<4
```

long R, after the operation is:

100000000000000000000000011010110000

So it seems to just be adding 0s to the end, without removing the digits at the beginning, and so not shifting them.

am I incorrect in my understanding of how LSL works, or is this some weird quirk of java? How can I get around this?

Comment: Is that the hexadecimal representation or the ***bit*** representation? It looks like the latter. And if it's the latter, is it a negative number?

Comment: And there really isn't such a beast as a "hexadecimal long". A long is a long, period. The String representation might be hexadecimal, but the number is long.

Comment: It is the Long.toBinaryString() print output of the hexadecimal number 0x8000006B

Comment: @RNPF [`toBinaryString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#toBinaryString-long-) returns *"the string representation of the unsigned long value represented by the argument in **binary (base 2)**"*, while [`toHexString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#toHexString-long-) returns *"the string representation of the unsigned long value represented by the argument in **hexadecimal (base 16)**"*. You are mixing terms. Please stop doing that. Quoted text is from the **documentation**, i.e. the javadoc, which is linked for you benefit.

Comment: you are aware that a `long` is 64 bits, not 32 right? Check [JLS 4.2. Primitive Types and Values](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2) So you must shift a little bit more before the bits *fall off* the left

Comment: "*get around*:: if you need only 32 bits use `int` instead of `long`, or *mask* the result `(R << 4) & 0xFFFF_FFFFL`

Comment: I like how Jacob came in, provided a helpful answer, while HovercraftFullOfEels and Andreas rushed to the neckbeard rescue, shouting about grammar, semantics, and wordchoice unrelated to the question, rapidly ensuring that not just did the question in no way move forward, but that Stackoverflow retains its reputation as a toxic shithole.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `R` is a positive `long`, its representation in binary is actually padded on the left by 32 zero bits; however, they're not shown when printing it to the console. With the zero bits, it would look like this:

```
0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_1000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0110_1011
```

When performing a left shift on this value, it simply shifts all bits to the left, discarding all bits that extend past the 64th bit.

Because the value in your example is only 32 bits, no bits are discarded, and the right is simply padded with zeros. The output is the following when shifted to the left by 4:

```
0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_1000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0110_1011_0000
```

---

In your comment, you stated that the value you're working with is `0x8000006B`, which is a negative number. Therefore, its representation looks like the following (before performing the left shift):

```
1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0110_1011
```

And after:

```
1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0110_1011_0000
```